# How can i send a information in Html to Django(backend)?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

How do I send a clicked link in html or selected information in the ComboBox to Django?

views.py

```
def musicList(request):
    musics = Song.objects.filter()
    print(musics)
    con = sqlite3.connect(str(request.user)+".db")
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("Select name From sqlite_master Where type='table';")
    tables = list()
    for i in cursor.fetchall():
        tables.append(i[0])
    context = {
        "musics":musics,
        "tables":tables,
    }
    return render(request,"musicList.html",context)
```

musicList.html

```
{% for music in musics %}
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{music.id}}</th>
                        <td>{{music.artist}}</td>
                        <td>{{music.song_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{music.song_type}}</td>
                        <td>{{music.owner}}</td>
                        <td>

                            <div class="dropdown">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Choice a Music List
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                {% for table in tables  %}
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="add_to_list/{{music.id}}" value="{{table}}">{{table}}</a>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                {% endfor %}
```

What do I do to return the value corresponding to the "value" of the link that the user clicked from the "dropdown-menu" to a different function in views.py

Comment: You need to post the html form or use ajax to send a "post" or "get" to the django back end process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods to communicate from the template to the view.

**1. Post method:**

Make a form with inputs, check-boxes.. etc and their values, and retrieve the values in the view:

```
request.POST.get('value')
```

**2. Via Url:**

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('add_to_list/<int:music_id>/<str:value>', views.musicList, name='musicList'),
...
]
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, music_id, value):
...
```

More advanced explanation in the official documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views).

You can also use

**Query Parameters:**

localhost:8000/?id=123

```
request.GET.get('id')
```